# How to create a getChildHtml block and call it in another

Tags: layout, template, blocks

Currently i'm working to redesign a custom Magento template.

I'm facing the following problem.

In file called: 2columns-left.phtml i am facing code like this several times:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

These code lines makes me think that they are calling blocks and the content in them by getting the name of .phtml file.

So i have file called `slider_layred_nav.phtml` and i want to call all the content in it in file `2columns-left.phtml` so i tried this code:

So in file `2columns-left.phtml` i put:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider_layred_nav') ?>
```

But it is just not displaying anything.

I assume that i have to do something with the `layout` but i have no idea what.

Can you help me our resolve this mystery ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> So in file 2columns-left.phtml i put:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider_layred_nav') ?>
> ```

First, check your spelling ("slider_layred_nav" => "slider_layered_nav"). You will then want to specify in some layout XML file (e.g. local.xml, which you can create in your theme) the following directive:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/template"
           name="slider_layered_nav"
           template="path/to/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

You may need to change the type based on the behaviors you need. Also, this directive needs to go inside a layout update handle. If you want this block to show up on every page, you would put it inside `<default />`:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template"
               name="slider_layered_nav"
               template="path/to/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```